# What could be a reason why a class can't be accessed from within another class's function?

Tags: python

I have 2 classes:

```
import follow
class User(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

import user
class Follow(object):
    def doSomething(self):
        u = User()

>> f = Follow()
>> f.doSomething()
>> NameError: global name 'User' is not defined
```

Is this causing a problem because both classes import each other?  Is there the equivalent of an import once?  Any other potential causes?  Thanks.

Comment: You can't import classes. You import from modules. And your modules can not have circular dependencies. Correct your code based on this information.

Comment: Is that code copy pasted exactly? That should compile, but without knowing what the follow and user modules are we have no idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
u = user.User()
```

or, alternatively:

```
from user import User
u = User()
```

Comment: Note also circular import problem.

Answer (score 1):

user.py

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

follow.py

```
from user import User

class Follow(object):
    def doSomething(self):
        u = User()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you're are importing `user` and then accessing `User`. Use `user.User` or (not as nice) `from user import User`.

Python treats modules as namespaces and so anything defined in the global scope of a module is only available as an attribute of the module in other namespaces that import it. There is no true 'global scope' in Python the way there is in some other languages.

The `from foo import bar` syntax allows one to bring an identifier directly into whatever scope it is executed in but later attempts to reload the module will no longer update that reference. There is also the problem of keeping track of where identifiers come from.

Also, you don't actually seem to be using `follow` in the `user` module. This shouldn't be a problem but if you are actually using it, then you should probably extend your example to include the use. How modules import each other can determine if this is actually allowed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use either

```
from user import *
```

(which is usually not recommended)

or create `User` objects using qualified name:

```
...
u = user.User()
```

Correct import

```
from user import User
```

doesn't work in your case, I guess, because of recursive imports.

Comment: When I do u = user.User() I get: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment

Comment: @ensnare, that most likely means that you have a variable named `user` at some point later in the function that raises that error.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a problem no matter.
If this a theoretical question then fine.
But if this an actual design then stop. following is an action. It should be a function in the class User to make any sence.

```
class User(object):
     def __init__(self):
          print "bleh"
     def follow(self,otheruser)
          following.append(otheruser)
```

this makes much more sense. following obviously is a list pulled from somewhere either a variable or directly from the database.